# What are the available event listeners in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

I've small experience with Sencha Touch 2 and Ext JS. I've a problem finding the available eventlinsteners in the framework (e.g. tap, show, hide, etc.) and their description. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, look at the [List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-listeners) in the docs, it has a [`listeners`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-listeners) configuration.
Inside this configuration you can specify events like `itemtap` or `hide`.

Lets look at the event [`itemtap`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-itemtap):

```
itemtap( this, index, target, record, e, eOpts )
```

It has 6 parameters you can use. The parameter `this` and `eOpts` are common for every event.
In  your code it looks like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
  fullscreen: true,
  itemTpl: '{title}',
  data: [
    { title: 'Item 1' },
    { title: 'Item 2' },
    { title: 'Item 3' },
    { title: 'Item 4' }
  ],
  listeners: {
    itemtap: function(cmp, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
      alert('Tapped on index: '+index);
    }
  }
});
```

This will alerts a message when you tap something in your list, good luck :).